# Split dataset from a vector

Tags: r, split, dataset

I'd like to select a  subset from `df` dataset using a vector `division_value` and apply the minimum for each `df1`, `df2`, and `df3`.

## Input

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9), x = runif(7), y = rnorm(7))
df

  id          x            y
  1 0.15316440  0.300897329
  3 0.17532977 -1.348602492
  4 0.02923305  0.573446127
  5 0.50233682 -0.415615162
  7 0.65804355  0.003661438
  8 0.52747538 -0.097006421
  9 0.12545577  2.043525380

division_value <- c(3, 6, 9)
```

## Expected Output

```
 > df1
 id          x            y
  1 0.15316440  0.300897329
  3 0.17532977 -1.348602492

apply(df1[, -1], 2, min)

 > df2
  id          x            y
  4 0.02923305  0.573446127
  5 0.50233682 -0.415615162

 apply(df2[, -1], 2, min)

 > df3
 id          x            y
  8 0.52747538 -0.097006421
  9 0.12545577  2.043525380

apply(df3[, -1], 2, min)
```

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your feedback! Sorry!

Comment: @r2evans getting sassy for his points.

Comment: Could you clarify how `division_value` defines your expected output?

Comment: @IanCampbell I had tried to use an upvote, but with less than 15 points of reputation isn't possible. I'm learning about the plataform. Thank you guys.

Comment: Wagner, I must have accidentally deleted my first question ... where does `id=7` go?

Comment: I'd like to select the minimum value for each `id = 1, 3` rows next, `id = 4, 5`, and `id = 8, 9`. But in my problem some ids there are not, e.g. `id = 2` and `id = 7`.

Comment: I think it's easy to use something like `cut` or `findInterval` to split the frame into a list of frames, but you reference `id=2` (which is not in your data) and `id=7` (which is in your data and somehow filtered out). What is your logic for 3, 6, 9? Is it something other than *"id is contained in the bins defined by `division_value`"*?

Comment: Sorry, `id = 7` there is in data. I desired to illustrate some missing ids. My problem is based on the price and count of the product (in this case, x and y, respectively) in time (named here as id). The products were observed in time `1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9`. I'd like to extract the minimum price (x) in the first 3 months (id), next, in a month less than 6 and greater than 3, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try an approach with `split`:

```
split.f <- split(f,sapply(f$id,function(x){sum(x > division_value)})+1)
split.f
$`1`
  id         x          y
1  1 0.6516738 -0.4115108
2  3 0.1255551  0.2522234

$`2`
  id         x          y
3  4 0.2672207 -0.8919211
4  5 0.3861141  0.4356833

$`3`
  id          x          y
5  7 0.01339033 -1.2375384
6  8 0.38238796 -0.2242679
7  9 0.86969085  0.3773956

result <- sapply(split.f,function(x){apply(x[,-1],2,min)})
result
           1          2           3
x  0.1255551  0.2672207  0.01339033
y -0.4115108 -0.8919211 -1.23753842
```

I know this does not match your expected output exactly, but is this what you actually want?

You could also set the names to match `division_value`:

```
colnames(result) <- division_value
result
           3          6           9
x  0.1255551  0.2672207  0.01339033
y -0.4115108 -0.8919211 -1.23753842
```